# Fullcalendar drag event outsite on a jquery ui droppable area

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, fullcalendar

I'm using the fullCalendar JqueryUi Plugin (v2.2.2). I need to have an external area to drop event from fullCalendar. 
I use the Jquery UI droppable on this external area but it doesn't accept my events when I drop on it.

This is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $( "#sidebar-waiting" ).droppable({
    tolerance : 'pointer',
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
        console.log('Dropped');
        console.log(event, ui);
    }
    });
});
</script>
<div class="sidebar-article" id="sidebar-waiting">
    <h2>En Attente</h2>
    ......
</div>
```

I've initiated my calendar with Editable : true.
I've tested my droppable area with another Jquery draggable item and it works.
I've seen on the fullcalendar doc that since v2.1 there is no more dependencies on Jquery UI  (http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_ui/Requirements/). Does it mean events are not Jquery draggable object ?

Thanks for your help